# ElasticSearch: querying most recent snapshot design

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, metrics

I'm trying to decide how to structure the data in ElasticSearch.

I have a system that is producing metrics on a daily basis.   I would like to put those metrics into ES so I could do some advances querying/sorting.  I also only care about the most recent data that's in there.  The system producing the data could also be late.

Currently I can think of two options:

1. I can have one index with a date column that contains the date that the metric was created.  I am unsure, however, of how to write the query so that if multiple days worth of data are in the index I filter it to just the most recent set.
2. I could also try and split the data up into different indexes (recent and past) and have some sort of process that migrates data from the recent index to the past index.  I think the challenge with this would be having downtime where the data is being moved and/or added into the recent.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to solving this problem with elastic search would be to store data in a form that allows historic querying, then again in a second form that allows querying the most recent data. For example if your metric update looked like:

```
{
   "type":"OperationsPerSecond",
   "name":"Questions",
   "value":10
}
```

Then it can be indexed into our current values index using a composite key constructed from the document (obviously, for this to work you'd need to be able to construct a composite key from your document!). For example, your identity for this document might be the type and name concatenated. You then leverage the [upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) API to allow you to write your updates to the same document:

```
POST current_metrics/_update/OperationsPerSecond-Questions
{
   "type":"OperationsPerSecond",
   "name":"Questions",
   "value":10
}
```

Every time you call this API with the same composite key it will update the existing document, rather than create a new document. This will give you an index that only contains a single record per metric you are monitoring, and you can query that index to get your most recent values.

To store your historic data, you change your primary key strategy, it would probably be most straightforward to use the [index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) and get elastic to generate a primary key for you.

```
POST all_metrics/_doc/
{
   "type":"OperationsPerSecond",
   "name":"Questions",
   "value":10
}
```

This API will create a new document for every request made to it. So as long as you have something in your data that you can use in an elastic [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-range-query.html), such as a field like `createdDate` with a value that looks like a date time, then you should be able to query historic data.

The main thing is, don't worry about duplicating your data for different purposes, elastic does a good job of compressing this stuff on disk and in memory. Storing data multiple times is called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and is a pretty common technique in data warehousing and big data.